# how to formulate a mapping relation

Tags: notation

The task is to find a compact (one-line) formulation for the following problem:

Consider a black box with two input parameters $X^{(L)},X^{(R)} \in R$ and two output parameters $X^{(I)},X^{(C)} \in R$. The block box maps $X^{(L)}$ to $X^{(I)}$ and $X^{(R)}$ to $X^{(C)}$ if some parameter $B=1$ but $X^{(L)}$ to $X^{(C)}$ and $X^{(R)}$ to $X^{(I)}$ for other values of $B$.

Is it right to formulate the mapping by the black box as "$\{X^{(L)},X^{(R)}\} \to \{X^{(I)},X^{(C)}\}$ iff $B=1$"?

Your support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation $\{X^{(L)}, X^{(R)}\} \to \{X^{(I)}, X^{(C)}\}$ says that both $X^{(L)}$ or $X^{(R)}$ gets mapped to $X^{(L)}$ or $X^{(R)}$. The “iff” is not clear.

I don't think you'll find a generally applicable compact notation for this. You could invent your notation if you use objects like this heavily. Otherwise, I don's think it pays off. Describing by words is usually good enough.

In some special contexts, you may use a shorcut. For example if your input values were $X_0$, $X_1$ and your output values were $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ and $B$ could be only $0$ or $1$, then something $X_i \mapsto Y_{(-1)^B i}$ may work.